# actualizar datos con arrays php

Tags: php, javascript

Interfaz
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo los siguientes paramentros obtenidos desde una interfaz que cree.

```
data_id=1,2,3,4,....,53

agente_id= 123,234

cantidad= 4
```

Deseo hacer un update a las filas según la cantidad y los `agente_id`.
Por ejemplo:
De los valores de `data_id` solo usaría 4 (`data_id=1,2,3,4`) y estos serian repartidos homogéneamente a cada agente(2 a cada uno).

De modo que la accion resultante seria algo asi:

```
UPDATE table_name SET agente_id=123 WHERE data_id=1
UPDATE table_name SET agente_id=123 WHERE data_id=2
UPDATE table_name SET agente_id=234 WHERE data_id=3
UPDATE table_name SET agente_id=234 WHERE data_id=4
```

Estoy usando php y ajax

Gracias espero puedan darme una mano :(

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Falta más contexto en tu pregunta y que muestres lo que has intentando. Actualmente tu pregunta parece decir: *hagan esto por mi*. Este no es el tipo de ayuda que se proporciona en esta comunidad. Se requiere que el interesado muestre un mínimo de interés por resolver su problema.

Comment: Hola solo no se como realizarlo, mi pregunta es para que me puedan ayudar guiandome.Gracias por responder

Comment: De todos modos falta contexto. Por ejemplo, ¿si son 6, deben ser repartidos entre dos agentes, entre tres agentes? Debes explicar con más claridad lo que quieres.

Comment: Si tienes 7 valores y 3 agentes, entonces querrías asignar 2 ids a cada agente y el sobrante al primer agente? digamos, repartiendo entre los agentes hasta que se acaben los data_id disponibles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorres el array ids, hasta cantidad ó que no hay mas ids
elegis el agente haciendo módulo del índice (dividido 2 para que cada uno tenga 2) por la cantidad de agentes

```
<?php

$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$qty = 5;
$agents = [123, 124]; 
$al = count($agents);
$il = count($ids);
$sql = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $qty && $i < $il; $i++) {
  $sql .= "UPDATE table_name SET agente_id=" . 
      $agents[$i/2 % $al] . " WHERE data_id=" . 
      $ids[$i] . ";".PHP_EOL;

}
var_dump($al,$il,$sql);
```

ver online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb5bba36fdf86e629f60e9f22748657a90aa73f1

en js:

```js
let ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    qty = 5,
    agents = [123, 124], 
    al = agents.length,
    il = ids.length;
let sql = "";
for (let i = 0; i < qty && i < il; i++) {
  sql = sql + "UPDATE table_name SET agente_id=" + 
     agents[Math.floor(i/2) % al ] + " WHERE data_id=" + 
     ids[i] + ";";
 
}
console.log(al,il,sql);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias logre adaptar tu ejemplo en mi codigo.